# locator not found when run selenium Rc script?

Tags: selenium-rc

The below are the form my web page...

```
        <div class="padding">
            <span class="new-line forty-six-bottom smaller">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam nec arcu id enim tincidunt vulputate. Sed et elementum nisi. Donec rhoncus feugiat pharetra. Donec sed augue id urna congue commodo et quis nulla. </span>
            <form id="detailsForm" action="/xyz/home/personaldetails" method="post">
             <span class="new-line fifteen-bottom">     
                <label for="title">
                    Title:
                </label>
                <em>*</em>
                <span class="field-and-error">

                <select id="title" name="title" class="required" style="width:234px;">
                    <option value="">Please select</option>
                    <option value="Mr" selected="selected">Mr</option><option value="Mrs">Mrs</option><option value="Miss">Miss</option><option value="Dr">Dr</option><option value="Ms">Ms</option><option value="Sir">Sir</option><option value="Prof">Prof</option><option value="Dame">Dame</option><option value="Lord">Lord</option><option value="Lady">Lady</option><option value="RH">RH</option><option value="Rev">Rev</option><option value="Sister">Sister</option><option value="Father">Father</option><option value="Other">Other</option>

                </select>

                </span>
            </span>
            <span class="new-line fifteen-bottom">  
                <label for="firstName">
                    First name:
                </label>
                <em>*</em>
                <span class="field-and-error">

                <input id="firstName" name="firstName" type="text" value="Sivaji" maxlength="50"/>

                </span>
            </span>
            <span class="new-line fifteen-bottom">      
                <label for="lastName">
                    Last name:
                </label>
                <em>*</em>
                <span class="field-and-error">

                <input id="lastName" name="lastName" type="text" value="Ganesan" maxlength="50"/>

                </span>
            </span>
When I copy the xpath from the above HTML, i am getting //*[@id="firstName"].
```

I am trying to use

`selenium.type("//input[@id='firstName']", "Chandra");` or

```
selenium.type("//*[@id='firstName']", "Chandra");
```

I am getting

```
`12:28:37.854 INFO - Got result: ERROR: Element //input[@id='firstName'] not found on 

session 96a10231817c40e5aa370660fd05ba45`
```

Can any one please clarify that why it is not identifying? The same is,if I  do recording in IDE, I can able to achieve,but in RC i could not.

Thanks
Chandra

Comment: Is that in iframe ? If so you need to switch the control to iframe before doing that operation.

Comment: No. it is not in iframe...

Comment: Is that locator showing that element properly in firebug. I think there might be two elements with same locator in that first one is hidden.

Comment: Given little brief about the HTML code.. no two elements are same..

Comment: Added wait command to load the page and used the selenium.type("//input[@id='firstName']", "Chandra"); it is working..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code is working absolutely fine with given html code snippet.

```
selenium.type("//*[@id='firstName']", "SantoshSarma");
```